# React component Game not rendered with route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render Game component using route. On clicking the link (defined in app.js), it directs to the desired page (game) but doesn't render the component Game. I tried to find answers but none of them helped. I'm absolutely new to react. Please help!! Thank You!!
Following are the code snippets:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import Game from './Game.js';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {
  HashRouter,
  Route,
  Link,
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
      <Route exact path = "/" component={App}>
          <Route path="game" component={Game}></Route>
      </Route>
   </Router >,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Link to= "game">Go</Link>
      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Game.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';



function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

export class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
      xIsNext: true,
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      squares: squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares);
    let status;
    if (winner && winner != 'draw') {
      status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
    }
    else if (winner && winner === 'draw'){
            status = "Both won!! It's a tie!! ";
    }
    else {
      status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
    else if(!squares.includes(null)) {
            return 'draw';
    }
  }
  return null;
}

registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you wrapping a route?

Try this:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App} />
<Route path="/game" component={Game} />
```

Routes should be treated as siblings, they work in the order they are written too.

Have a look at this page for more information: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

**EDIT Router example:**
Just replace your router with this.

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/game" component={Game} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: I tried to put place both routes separately inside a div. It's still not rendering Game.. :(

Comment: <Router>
      <div>
      <Route exact path = "/" component={App}></Route>
      <Route path="game" component={Game}></Route>
      </div>
  </Router >

Comment: Without div its showing the error..  A <Router> may have only one child element

Comment: Could you please also explain what was wrong previously?? I'm learning..

Comment: You had some slight issues with your syntax, your path for game didn't have the required "/" before "game". You don't need to close the route tag either, just end it with a `/` like this `<Route ... />`